# php Get url param with symbols

Tags: php, parameters

Im trying to get a url param value with symbols in php string `&value=xdz_#*`

```
$val = $_GET['value'];
$val = urldecode($_GET['value']);
```

This ones always returns the value without the symbols `#*` like: `xdz_`

any sugestion will be appreciated

Comment: Your URL should be properly URL encoded. Those symbols are not a problem when the encoded is correct. Please share the raw URL so we can identify the issue with it.

Comment: Thats right, encoding it solve the problem, thanks!!

Comment: Please accept the answer I posted so we can close the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extracting from my previous comment that brought the answer:

Your URL should be properly URL encoded. Those symbols are not a problem when the encoded is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was encoding the parameter to the url, I do it in csharp and is like this:

```
string value_encoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value);
```

Then when I write the url:

```
&value=value_encoded
```